# "Post" method test result error in JMeter API testing

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

I tried to run a POST method for API testing in JMeter, I have sent the parameters as needed, but still it shows cannot post.

What should I do to make it work?

[user add post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEUpG.png)

[response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee856.png)

Comment: Please add your Post user settings

Comment: i have added it

Comment: What about the server name and port?

Comment: just a localhost server with port 3000 and path as /user/data

Comment: There are text fields that seems empty for server and port

Comment: i have tried both by adding/removing those fields. doesn;t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post request, you need to provide server name or IP address and port number respectively. If it still  doesn't work, try changing the path by adding /api then /user/data. it works in some cases.
Hope this works out!

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing an API my expectation is that you need to send either JSON or XML payload using "Body Data" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

You will also need [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

References:

- [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right)

Another way of building a web service test plan is executing the request(s) according to your test scenario using a 3rd-party tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) and recording them via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

Comment: I have done it all as you mentioned though doesn't work!